# Retrieve Embed link by onclick

Tags: javascript, embed, alert, src

Could someone tell me why I always get the same embed link by onclick?
This code gives me a whole list with videos;

If I click the link I would like to get the src of this link.
If I inspect the element the embed is right, but when I click on it gives me always an alert with the embed code of the first video of the list.

this is the code of the videolist:

```
<ul class="video_list">
      <?php
        $result_video = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM guestlist_tvs ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 16");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_video)) { 
      ?>
        <li rel='<?php echo $row['video_music_cat'];?>' cat='<?php echo $row['video_cat'];?>'>
          <a onclick="test();" href="#" src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $row['youtube_id']; ?>?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent' class='video_thumb' id="link">
            <div class="video_img_wrapper"><img class='video_img'src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $row['youtube_id']; ?>/maxresdefault.jpg" width='240px' height='160px'>
            <img class="play_button" src="images/play_button.png" alt="play" /></img></div>
            <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
            <p><?php //echo $row['description']; ?></p>
          </a>
        </li>
      <?php 
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
      ?>
      </ul>
```

and this is my javascript code;

```
function test() {
alert(document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("src"));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you dont use jquery library ?

Comment: Could you tell me what you mean by that or give an example?
I tried a lot of codes, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I have posted my answer and sample code with jquery library

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using jquery and click event

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.video_thumb').click(function () {
        alert(this.getAttribute("src"));
    });

});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6tn9o39j/)